# Is it possible to change a field value after a certain number of days?

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I am trying to create a SharePoint calendar for filing of leave. The initial value of the "Status" is "New" from the choices: "New", "Approved", and "Disapproved". If the supervisor has not changed the "Status" after 3 days, it should automatically change to "Approved". I tried to use calculated field and using an IF statement. That's the only way I can think of but it doesn't work. I need your help as of the best possible way to implement this.

Answer (score 3):

We have following options

1. SharePoint designer 2013 workflows: In workflow you can use
   **Pause** action to set a variable value after specified days. If you environment is SharePoint 2013 then it's work
2. Create a timer job. Verify the items everyday. If difference between item created date and current date is greater than 3 days then change the status of the items which meet the condition.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a workflow to start when an item is created.
2. Pause for a duration (in your case 3 days)
3. Create an IF statement (if currentitem:Status is equal to "New") then set the status field for current item to approved.

Answer (score 1):

In case where timer job and workflow solutions are not feasible.

Create a console application and scheduled to run it daily. Write code to check and update the status based on created field. An aspx page in layouts can be created if console application is not possible. This solution doesn't have workflow limitations or restarting iis.